# How to get only nested params in strong parameter in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I get the only `need_attributes` from this?

```
def needy_params
  params.require(:needy).permit(:user_name, :user_email, :needs_attributes: [:name, :description, :amount_required, :country_id, :city_id])
end
```

Is it possible that I get only `needs_attributes` from this or write new method like this?

```
def need_param
  params.require(:needy.needs_attributes).permit(:name, :description, :amount_required, :country_id, :city_id)
end
```

Comment: name = params["needy"]["needs_attributes"]["0"]["name"] I get by this but I do not want like this..It make my controller dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
def needs_attributes_param
  params.require(:needy).require(:needs_attributes).permit(
    :name, :description, :amount_required, :country_id, :city_id
  )
end
```